# NativeScript app won't run on IOS

Tags: ios, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am evaluating nativescript, but I cannot get it to work on IOS. It all works well when running on an Android device/emulator though (from a mac).

I set everything up according to the [tutorial](http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tutorial/ng-chapter-1#11-install-nativescript-and-configure-your-environment) on the nativescript site, and tried again with a fresh checkout of [angular2-seed-advanced](https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular2-seed-advanced#nativescript-app).

- When running on an **IOS-Simulator** the apps start, but do not get past the splash screen (groceries shows its own logo, seed the nativescript logo).

  ```
  Successfully deployed on device with identifier 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'.
  Aug 30 00:13:35 macmini com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy.launchd_sim[59384] (UIKitApplication:org.nativescript.groceries[0x9af7][60400]): Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9
  ```
- When trying to run on an **IOS-Device** (IPhone 5), I get another error during the attempt to deploy (same for both projects), so the app does not even get deployed to the device. Seems to a dependency of nativescript (FiberFuture?) not getting a promise resolved when waiting for a physical device to call back (the Simulator seems to get past this step).

  ```
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
  at FiberFuture.Future.wait (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fibers/future.js:566:15)
  at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/errors.js:128:33
  ```

  See this full --log trace

  ```
  macmini:nativescript xxx$ tns run ios --log trace
  execFile: /usr/local/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb "help"
  execFile: /usr/local/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb "help"
  spawn: /usr/local/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb "--help"
  Socket {
    connecting: false,
    _hadError: false,
    _handle: 
     Pipe {
       bytesRead: 0,
       _externalStream: {},
       fd: 15,
       writeQueueSize: 0,
       owner: [Circular],
       onread: [Function: onread],
       reading: true },
    _parent: null,
    _host: null,
    _readableState: 
     ReadableState {
       objectMode: false,
       highWaterMark: 16384,
       buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
       length: 0,
       pipes: null,
       pipesCount: 0,
       flowing: null,
       ended: false,
       endEmitted: false,
       reading: true,
       sync: false,
       needReadable: true,
       emittedReadable: false,
       readableListening: false,
       resumeScheduled: false,
       defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
       ranOut: false,
       awaitDrain: 0,
       readingMore: false,
       decoder: null,
       encoding: null },
    readable: true,
    domain: null,
    _events: 
     { end: { [Function: g] listener: [Function: onend] },
       finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
       _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
       close: [Function] },
    _eventsCount: 4,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _writableState: 
     WritableState {
       objectMode: false,
       highWaterMark: 16384,
       needDrain: false,
       ending: false,
       ended: false,
       finished: false,
       decodeStrings: false,
       defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
       length: 0,
       writing: false,
       corked: 0,
       sync: true,
       bufferProcessing: false,
       onwrite: [Function],
       writecb: null,
       writelen: 0,
       bufferedRequest: null,
       lastBufferedRequest: null,
       pendingcb: 0,
       prefinished: false,
       errorEmitted: false,
       bufferedRequestCount: 0,
       corkedRequestsFree: CorkedRequest { next: null, entry: null, finish: [Function] } },
    writable: false,
    allowHalfOpen: false,
    destroyed: false,
    _bytesDispatched: 0,
    _sockname: null,
    _writev: null,
    _pendingData: null,
    _pendingEncoding: '',
    server: null,
    _server: null }
  Exec uname -a 
   stdout: Darwin macmini 15.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0: Thu Jun 23 18:25:34 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3248.60.10~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

   stderr: 
  Exec npm -v 
   stdout: 3.10.3

   stderr: 
  spawn: java "-version"
  Exec node-gyp -v 
   stdout: v3.4.0

   stderr: 
  Exec xcodebuild -version 
   stdout: Xcode 7.3.1
  Build version 7D1014

   stderr: 
  Exec gem which xcodeproj 
   stdout: /Users/rob/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.2.0/lib/xcodeproj.rb

   stderr: 
  Exec pod --version 
   stdout: 1.0.1

   stderr: 
  Exec '/usr/local/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb' version 
   stdout: Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.36
  Revision af05c7354fe1-android

   stderr: 
  spawn: /usr/local/opt/android-sdk/tools/android "-h"
  Result when throw error is false:
  { stdout: '\n       Usage:\n       android [global options] action [action options]\n       Global options:\n  -s --silent     : Silent mode, shows errors only.\n  -v --verbose    : Verbose mode, shows errors, warnings and all messages.\n     --clear-cache: Clear the SDK Manager repository manifest cache.\n  -h --help       : Help on a specific command.\n\n                                                                    Valid\n                                                                    actions\n                                                                    are\n                                                                    composed\n                                                                    of a verb\n                                                                    and an\n                                                                    optional\n                                                                    direct\n                                                                    object:\n-    sdk              : Displays the SDK Manager window.\n-    avd              : Displays the AVD Manager window.\n-   list              : Lists existing targets or virtual devices.\n-   list avd          : Lists existing Android Virtual Devices.\n-   list target       : Lists existing targets.\n-   list device       : Lists existing devices.\n-   list sdk          : Lists remote SDK repository.\n- create avd          : Creates a new Android Virtual Device.\n-   move avd          : Moves or renames an Android Virtual Device.\n- delete avd          : Deletes an Android Virtual Device.\n- update avd          : Updates an Android Virtual Device to match the folders\n                        of a new SDK.\n- create project      : Creates a new Android project.\n- update project      : Updates an Android project (must already have an\n                        AndroidManifest.xml).\n- create test-project : Creates a new Android project for a test package.\n- update test-project : Updates the Android project for a test package (must\n                        already have an AndroidManifest.xml).\n- create lib-project  : Creates a new Android library project.\n- update lib-project  : Updates an Android library project (must already have\n                        an AndroidManifest.xml).\n- create uitest-project: Creates a new UI test project.\n- update adb          : Updates adb to support the USB devices declared in the\n                        SDK add-ons.\n- update sdk          : Updates the SDK by suggesting new platforms to install\n                        if available.\n',
    stderr: '',
    exitCode: 1 }
  Exec mono --version 
   stdout: Mono JIT compiler version 4.4.1 (Nightly 4.4.1.0/4747417 Tue Jul  5 17:44:19 BST 2016)
  Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
          TLS:           normal
          SIGSEGV:       altstack
          Notification:  kqueue
          Architecture:  amd64
          Disabled:      none
          Misc:          softdebug 
          LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
          GC:            sgen

   stderr: 
  Exec git --version 
   stdout: git version 2.7.4 (Apple Git-66)

   stderr: 
  Exec gradle -v 
   stdout:  
   stderr: /bin/sh: gradle: command not found

  Exec "javac" -version 
   stdout:  
   stderr: javac 1.8.0_102

  System information:
  { procInfo: 'nativescript/2.2.1',
    platform: 'darwin',
    os: 'Darwin macmini 15.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0: Thu Jun 23 18:25:34 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3248.60.10~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64\n',
    shell: '/bin/bash',
    dotNetVer: null,
    procArch: 'x64',
    nodeVer: 'v6.3.1',
    npmVer: '3.10.3',
    javaVer: '1.8.0',
    nodeGypVer: 'v3.4.0\n',
    xcodeVer: 'Xcode 7.3.1\nBuild version 7D1014\n',
    xcodeprojGemLocation: '/Users/rob/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.2.0/lib/xcodeproj.rb\n',
    itunesInstalled: true,
    cocoapodVer: '1.0.1',
    adbVer: 'Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.36',
    androidInstalled: true,
    monoVer: '4.4.1',
    gitVer: '2.7.4 (Apple Git-66)',
    gradleVer: null,
    javacVersion: '1.8.0_102' }
  Initializing analytics statuses.
  Analytics statuses: 
  { TrackFeatureUsage: 1, TrackExceptions: 1 }
  Trying to track feature 'CLI' with value 'run'.
  Looking for project in '/Users/xxx/workspace/angular2-seed-advanced/nativescript'
  Project directory is '/Users/xxx/workspace/angular2-seed-advanced/nativescript'.
  Analytics statuses: 
  { TrackFeatureUsage: 1, TrackExceptions: 1 }
  Trying to track feature 'CLI' with value 'run|ios'.
  startLookingForDevices; platform is iOS
  Found device with identifier 'c28457499xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  Exec ps cax | grep launchd_sim 
   stdout: 51449   ??  S      0:01.63 launchd_sim

   stderr: 
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
      at FiberFuture.Future.wait (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fibers/future.js:566:15)
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/errors.js:128:33
      at Function.settle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fibers/future.js:249:26)
      at FiberFuture.Future.wait (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fibers/future.js:565:10)
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/services/commands-service.js:84:106
      at Function.settle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fibers/future.js:249:26)
      at FiberFuture.Future.wait (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fibers/future.js:565:10)
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/yok.js:208:124
      at Function.settle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fibers/future.js:249:26)
      at FiberFuture.Future.wait (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fibers/future.js:565:10)
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/services/commands-service.js:51:55
      at Function.settle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fibers/future.js:249:26)
      at FiberFuture.Future.wait (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fibers/future.js:565:10)
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/errors.js:128:33
      at Function.settle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fibers/future.js:249:26)
      at FiberFuture.Future.wait (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fibers/future.js:565:10)
      - - - - -
      at IOSSimulator.Object.defineProperty.get [as deviceInfo] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/mobile/ios/simulator/ios-simulator-device.js:15:43)
      at IOSSimulatorDiscovery.DeviceDiscovery.addDevice (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/mobile/mobile-core/device-discovery.js:16:28)
      at IOSSimulatorDiscovery.createAndAddDevice (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/mobile/mobile-core/ios-simulator-discovery.js:58:14)
      at IOSSimulatorDiscovery.checkForDevices (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/mobile/mobile-core/ios-simulator-discovery.js:27:26)
      at IOSSimulatorDiscovery.startLookingForDevices (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/mobile/mobile-core/ios-simulator-discovery.js:20:21)
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/mobile/mobile-core/devices-service.js:215:50
      at Function.settle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fibers/future.js:249:26)
      at FiberFuture.Future.wait (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fibers/future.js:565:10)
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/mobile/mobile-core/devices-service.js:330:48
      at Function.settle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fibers/future.js:249:26)
      at FiberFuture.Future.wait (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fibers/future.js:565:10)
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/services/platform-service.js:366:103
      at Function.settle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fibers/future.js:249:26)
      at FiberFuture.Future.wait (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fibers/future.js:565:10)
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/services/platform-service.js:402:58
      at Function.settle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fibers/future.js:249:26)
  Analytics statuses: 
  { TrackFeatureUsage: 1, TrackExceptions: 1 }
  Trying to track feature 'CLI' with value 'help'.
  List of registered commands: /?, appstore, appstore|upload, autocomplete, autocomplete|disable, autocomplete|enable, autocomplete|status, build, build|android, build|ios, create, debug, debug|android, debug|ios, deploy, dev-generate-help, dev-generate-messages, dev-post-install, dev-preuninstall, dev-test, dev-test|android, dev-test|ios, device, device|android, device|get-file, device|ios, device|list-applications, device|list-files, device|log, device|put-file, device|run, device|stop, device|uninstall, doctor, emulate, emulate|android, emulate|ios, error-reporting, help, info, init, install, livesync, platform, platform|add, platform|clean, platform|remove, platform|update, plugin, plugin|add, plugin|find, plugin|install, plugin|remove, plugin|search, plugin|update, prepare, publish, publish|ios, run, run|android, run|ios, test, test|android, test|init, test|ios, usage-reporting
  Reading help for command 'run|ios'. FileName is 'run-ios.md'.
  ```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Kansen and @tj-vantoll!

I got it solved with both solutions. First installing node via [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) (6.5.0), because as non-root user I had to use sudo to install nativescript globally, during the installation there are some permission errors like "root has no permission to write in /Users/myUser"

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.6/install.sh | bash

nvm install node
nvm use node
# re-open terminal or re-source your bash config e.g.:
source ~/.bashrc
```

Then do a fresh global install of nativescript (now in new nvm node instance, so cache clean and remove can be omitted, plus no sudo needed because this instance is installed in ~/.nvm/...)

```
npm i -g nativescript
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try with Node version below the 6,

Nativescript Manual Setup mention "The latest Node.js 0.10.x, 0.12.x, 4.x or 5.x stable official release"

You can set the node version you want to use with [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) (node version management)

I hope this will fix your issue.

Comment: NativeScript supports Node 6.x now, so I don’t believe that this is the problem. That being said, this error is a real odd one, and I’m not sure what’s up.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that this is an issue with your npm cache. Can you try the following?

```
npm cache clean
npm remove -g nativescript
npm remove -g nativescript (yes twice)
npm install -g nativescript
```

My source is https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/1862#issuecomment-227444053, and I’ve ran into this sort of error before and had to reinstall.

Comment: I tried this with node 6.x and the new installation got until this point, where its been hanging for half an hour now (needed to run global install on mac with sudo):

Comment: /usr/local/bin/tns -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/bin/nativescript.js

Comment: > fibers@1.0.13 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fibers

Comment: > node build.js || nodejs build.js

Comment: gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/Users/rob/.node-gyp/6.5.0"

Comment: gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fibers/.node-gyp"

Comment: I will try this again with nvm installed node, this should be less of a problem regarding the permissions for global installs

Comment: well ... still downloading the nvm node image ... will try the rest tomorrow

Comment: ok, so downloading nvm image 6.5.0 is done, and installing nativescript global worked well now, without complaining about permissions. The app is running on ios now. Thanks a lot!

I'm not sure though if it was that weird chache problem or just a messed up installation through the `sudo npm i -g nativescript` which was not allowed to write to /Users/myUser as root (sudo).